# Cannot find /etc/apache2/sites-available/default when configuring Apache

Tags: apache2

I followed the instruction [here](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/configure-php-environment-ubuntu.html) to configure a PHP development environment. First:

```
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

It succeeded, and `It works!` is outputted in `http://localhost/`. Then:

```
sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/default /etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite
```

An error happened here:

```
cp: cannot stat ‘/etc/apache2/sites-available/default’: No such file or directory
```

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10. I searched the web but didn't get anything that looked promising. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT:

```
 $ ls /etc/apache2/sites-available
 000-default.conf  default-ssl.conf
```

Comment: Please post the output of: ls /etc/apache2/sites-available

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The tutorial you are using is based on an older version of Ubuntu.

13.10 ships a newer apache configuration, where the file you are looking for is named `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`.

Note the `.conf` at the end, which is now required for apache to pick up on the files. So make sure the config you are creating for your site also has `.conf` as its extension.

Comment: Thanks. BTW, I did't find `<Directory /var/www/>` in this file. Does that mean I don't need to change the Directory directive?

Comment: I think some of the defaults must've changed because now the file seems to not include as much stuff. My guess is that you can add in your customizations as usual in 000-default.conf, just make sure you nest it properly, see line "DocumentRoot /var/www" which should be somewhere near line 12 in the default (stock/unmodified) one.

Answer (score 8):

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` is the configuration file for the default site, only. You can add as many sites as you want, with their config files located in this same directory.

The apache global configuration file you're looking for is located in:

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

As @drc mentioned, a lot of things changed in recent versions of Ubuntu.