# my /etc/apache2/sites-available/default appears blank

Tags: server, 14.04, apache2

hi i am newly switched to `ubuntu 14.04` i am installing `laravel` on my `lamp server` in [tutorial](http://www.dev-metal.com/install-laravel-4-ubuntu-12-04-lts/) its written to edit this file `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/default` but when i tried to open the same file in my `nano editor` the file appears blank ie. nothing to search as its asked in tutorial, how can i configure my `default` as suggested in the tutorial.

Comment: Which version of Apache are you using? The config files have changed between versions 2.2 and 2.4, as the article states. The current Apache version would be 2.4.7.

Comment: i am using same apache 2.4.7

Comment: Did you disable the default site perhaps? Please confirm `ls /etc/apache2/sites-available/default` shows it exists.

Comment: Duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/386382/cannot-find-etc-apache2-sites-available-default-when-configuring-apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try searching for the same in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
Type- gksu gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

In this file you will find AllowOverride and the DocumentRoot. Edit them as you want.

Comment: thanks for help @raj_praveen but this file is also blank

Comment: Go to your browser and type localhost in the URL box. If the Apache2 default page appears, then the apache server is working properly and the files should not be blank. If not try re-installing apache using: sudo apt-get install apache2

Answer (score 0):

I am using `Ubuntu 18.04 Subsystem for Windows 10` and I had that problem plus empty apache2.conf file too.
To get back your ordinary files you have to recover your `apache2-utils` by using the following commands in your terminal :

> sudo apt-get remove --purge apache2 apache2-utils
>
> sudo apt-get install --reinstall  apache2 apache2-utils

But don't forget to take your previous work from `/var/www/html` if you have.

Comment: I'm getting this error when trying to restart apache:  Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do a version of my site that worked with the windows wampp seems that linux variants are not the same or faulty.  I was able to make a share across a network work but under apache its not working.
I have tried to change all these conf and can not seem to find the right one to allow images to traverse and build on the webpage.
I am thinking there is a configuration issue or format issue.  SO a blank file is more of a problem but would love a example format to build with.  I installed winpress was unimpressed and removed it, so might be something to do and rebuild the apache files.
I found this tip so will try it myself.

Comment: Reinstall fixed a few issues not the one that I am working on though. Overall still a good tip.